# I am trying to sort by date with PANDAS but does not work, always reading a string

Tags: python, pandas

```
    26/05/19,Atalanta-Sassuolo,3 - 1
    26/05/19,Cagliari-Udinese,1 - 2
    26/05/19,Fiorentina-Genoa,0 - 0
    26/05/19,Inter-Empoli,2 - 1
    26/05/19,Roma-Parma,2 - 1
    26/05/19,Spal-Milan,2 - 3
    26/05/19,Sampdoria-Juventus,2 - 0
    26/05/19,Torino-Lazio,3 - 1
    25/05/19,Bologna-Napoli,3 - 2
    25/05/19,Frosinone-Chievo,0 - 0 
    20/05/19,Lazio-Bologna,3 - 3
```

CSV file start

```
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=['date','games','result'])
    df = df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True)
    print(df)

    output
             date              games result
    129  01/03/19     Cagliari-Inter  2 - 1
    358  01/09/18      Bologna-Inter  0 - 3
    ...
    90   31/03/19        Inter-Lazio  0 - 1
    359  31/08/18         Milan-Roma  2 - 1
    379  31/10/18        Milan-Genoa  2 - 1
```

It reads the string of the date but I cannot find the right command to parse the date, it should be easy  but isn't

Comment: try `pd.read_csv(filename, names=['date','games','result'], parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: The start of the output is still wrong : 158 2018-02-08        Chievo-Roma  0 - 3
156 2018-02-09        Parma-Inter  0 - 1
157 2018-02-09  Fiorentina-Napoli  0 - 0   the first one should be in date 2018/08/18

Comment: What I need to nail down what to do is an example of the actual csv file you are trying to read.  Otherwise, we're just guessing and wasting time.

Comment: Beginning of the CSV file             26/05/19,Atalanta-Sassuolo,3 - 1\n
26/05/19,Cagliari-Udinese,1 - 2
26/05/19,Fiorentina-Genoa,0 - 0
26/05/19,Inter-Empoli,2 - 1
26/05/19,Roma-Parma,2 - 1
26/05/19,Spal-Milan,2 - 3
26/05/19,Sampdoria-Juventus,2 - 0
26/05/19,Torino-Lazio,3 - 1
25/05/19,Bologna-Napoli,3 - 2
25/05/19,Frosinone-Chievo,0 - 0
20/05/19,Lazio-Bologna,3 - 3

Comment: [edit] your post.  We can't read it in the comments.

Comment: do you mean `ascending=False`?

Comment: It owrks nowwith ascending=True, Ihad an error in copying your first answer.  Sry

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have whitespace in your dates. Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=['date','games','result'])

df['date'] = df.date.str.strip()

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

df = df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True)
```

Comment: still wrong        date                 games result
357 2018-01-09        Parma-Juventus  1 - 2
358 2018-01-09         Bologna-Inter  0 - 3
310 2018-01-10        Sampdoria-Spal  2 - 1
249 2018-01-12           Spal-Empoli  2 - 2
248 2018-01-12   Fiorentina-Juventus  0 - 3
..         ...                   ...    ...
72  2019-07-04        Inter-Atalanta  0 - 0
73  2019-07-04        Lazio-Sassuolo  2 - 2
75  2019-07-04        Udinese-Empoli  3 - 2
76  2019-07-04  Fiorentina-Frosinone  0 - 1
74  2019-07-04         Cagliari-Spal  2 - 1

Comment: Try the updated version, I've specified the format explicitly.

Comment: Still not working, I put the start of CSV file in the post

Comment: I've loaded your `.csv` and the edited asnwer worked fine.